# Java implementation for livecount?

Tags: java, memcached

Is there a java implementation of [livecount](https://github.com/gregbayer/gae-livecount) [[blog]](http://gbayer.com/projects/livecount/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not precisely that particular app, but it wouldn't be that hard to make an atomic incrementing service using Java and [Redis](http://redis.io/). Just make certain not to rely on Redis persistence any more  than you would memcached's and snapshot/replicate the data to something more permanent but perhaps slower periodically.